# Update or push object into nested array in found document mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have this mongoose Schema:

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    trim: true
  },
  userId: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "user ID required."],
    unique: [true, "user ID must be unique"]
  },
  votes: [
    {
      pollId: type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      candidates: [
        {
          candidateId: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  role: {
    type: String,
    enum: ["user", "admin"],
    default: "user"
  }
});
```

I find user first, because I want to authorize the user. and now I want to update some parts. just want to be clear, I want to update some parts of a found *user* document.

I have multiple polls that user can vote for multiple candidates in each one. so if user has not voted at all, *votes* array will be empty, and we have to push first *pollId* and also first candidateId that he/she votes. and if the *pollId* exists,we have to find that subdocument first by *pollId* then we should just add *candidateId* inside candidates array.

how can I do this? preferred is just one operation not multiple. and if I can get updated *user* its better.

if it's not clear let me know. I'll try to explain more.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this

```js
function updateUsersVotes(userId, newVote) {
  User.findById(userId)
    .exec()
    .then((dbUser) => {
      if (!dbUser.votes.length) {     // no votes yet
        dbUser.votes.push(newVote);
      } else {                        // check current votes
        const voteIndex = dbUser.votes.findIndex((vote) => vote.pollId.toString() === newVote.pollId.toString());
        if (voteIndex > 0) {          // if the incoming vote pollId matches an existing pollId
          dbUser.votes[voteIndex].candidates.push(...newVote.candidates);
        } else {
          dbUser.votes.push(newVote); // if the incoming pollId can't be found, then add it.
        }
      }
      dbUser.save({ validateBeforeSave: true }); // update the user.
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      handleError(error);             // you should always handle your errors.
    });
}
```

Comment: both pollId's are objects, with different references, if two objects have different references their comparison will always result in "false" even if their values are the same, you must add .toString() to the end of pollId comparison.

Comment: @Ako nice catch! I've definitely ran into that error multiple times.